# Angular One-time bind conditionally OR unbind listener when a specific value is set

Tags: javascript, angularjs, one-time-binding

I've something like below in DOM:

```
 <div ng-if="variant"
    ng-include="'size-picker.html'">
 </div>
```

And in controller:

```
$scope.variant = false;
// after some unknown time there may be:
$scope.variant = true;
```

I wanted to show that div when `variant` is true. So,

`$scope.variant` will start by `false`. After some time it may/may not become `true`. When `$scope.variant` became `true` it's never gonna change it's value. So what I want is one-time bind that `ng-if` once `$scope.variant` is `true`.

An approach like:

```
<div ng-if="::variant"
    ng-include="'size-picker.html'">
</div>
```

will stop binding when it's false.

I can achieve it by stop assigning `false` to `variant` in the first time, but it's not possible in my case.

How can I unbind the ng-if when `variant` is `true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$watch`, to unregister a `binding` or a `scope`

`$watch` returns a `deregistration` function.

You can unregister a `$watch` with the function returned by the `$watch` call:

```
var unwatch = $scope.$watch('variant', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if(newValue == true)
    {
        unwatch();
    }
});
```

**So, once your variant becomes true, the watch on it is removed, and the binding gets stopped.**

```js
var app = angular.module( "Demo", [] );

app.controller(
  "AppController",
  function( $scope ) {
    $scope.count = 0;
    $scope.after_unwatch = false;

    var unbindWatcher = $scope.$watch(
      "count",
      function( count ) {
        alert( "Watching click count." );
        if ( count >= 5 ) {
          $scope.after_unwatch = true;
          unbindWatcher();
        }

      }
    );


  
    $scope.incrementCount = function() {
      $scope.count++;
    };

  }
);
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <div  ng-app="Demo" ng-controller="AppController">
    <h1>
      Unbinding $watch() Listeners In AngularJS
    </h1>

    <p>
      <a ng-click="incrementCount()">Click it for five times, and after that watch on `count` is removed.</a>
      &raquo;

    </p>

    <p ng-show="after_unwatch">
      <em>The watch on click is removed.</a>
    </p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Run this code**

[Here is a plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/TIL8HioWhrwVhufFBifo?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks. So you are saying angular will stop watching on that variable completely? even it's dependent on other places like DOM?

Comment: yes, once you put that scope variable in `$watch` function, its scoped is removed based on a condition.

Comment: let me give you an example, posting it.

Comment: No. I switched tasks now. Thinks it will work okay for me. Thanks @Sravan

Answer (score 2):

The docs say:

> One-time expressions will stop recalculating once they are stable,
>   which happens after the first digest if the expression result is a
>   non-undefined value.

So you could start with an undefined value.

Comment: In my case, It will start with false. It's a huge codebase. I have limits to do that.

Comment: In case Sravan's answer doesn't work for your specific case, you could use a different undefined variable for the ngIf, and then monitor `variant`'s state, updating that variable appropriately. Not optimal, but with difficult constraints sometimes that's the best we can manage

Comment: That's a nice way doing that.